# What's the difference between an android phone and an Android tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I want to know the difference between an android phone and an Android tablet follow condition below:

```
- Life circle of Activity and Fragment

- Api supported for our config, i.e. : Mac address, ip address, cell number, IMSI, ...

- How about the orientation, notificaion.

- Multilanguage on Tablet.

- UI on table, which widget/control should change to avoid the issue.
```

Please help me to clarify them?

Thank you so much!

Comment: No one "can help you for your question", since you did not really ask a question...

Comment: @arkascha Well he asked a question. I implore you to look up what a question is. Whether its adequate for Stackoverflow is a different story. Its obvious he took no time or made no effort to look this info up. Otherwise this "question" would have never been asked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 4 points are the same on both Phone or Tablet.

Regarding to the last one, the most significant difference between Phone and Tablet is that Tablet might use a Tablet-Style UI while phone doesn't. This is because that Tablet often has a lower density of screen pixels.

And what's more, Tablet often does not have Phone call functions. And for those Tablet that doesn't have a 3G or 4G module, GPS often is missed either.

I suppose you have been very familiar with Android Phones' characteristics, here are some useful links about Android Tablet for your reference.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2013/04/update-on-tablet-app-guidelines-and.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2013/04/tablet-optimization-tips-in-google-play.html

Comment: @robin not all tablets don't have phone call functions and/or GPS. also, since the screen is large, it's very recommended to use fragment-based UI design, while it's not so crucial to use them for smartphones.

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes you are right. Since the question is so broad I can only give the answer which fits the most conditions.

Comment: @Robin you should show him some links to google io lectures, so that he will learn how to develop for tablets.

Comment: @androiddeveloper roger that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: your links are good, but i meant real lectures, from here: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html#android-track , https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions#android , https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions#t-android

Comment: @Robin: I want to know that all api I say above still work on Android tablet?

Comment: @Luc Le yes, they all works the same, for sure.

Comment: @Robin: Everything are same android phone, except UI and hardware?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Everything are same android phone, except UI and hardware?

Comment: @LucLe UI is the same too, it's just recommended to think differently since the screen is larger. hardware can also be about the same. a google lecturer has said in the past that the whole difference between a tablet and a smartphone is the screen size. best thing is that you watch lectures of how to design your apps to work well on tablets, especially the part that talks about fragments.